# a lot less now too meaning

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

Is my understanding of the phrase ***a lot less now too*** in below context correct?

> I go to stadium a lot less now too.

means

> Now also, I go to stadium very rarely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I go to *the* stadium a lot less now (too).

"too" would not be used with this sentence by itself. There would need to be a previous phrase, for example:

> I go to the city a lot less now, and I go to *the* stadium a lot less now too.

Now if we substitute the meaning you asked about:

> I go to the city a lot less now. Now also, I go to *the* stadium very rarely.

Basically it is OK, but "a lot less" means "a lot less than before". It could have been 200 days/year before and now it is 50 days/year.

However, "very rarely" is "hardly at all", and should be a very small number in any case.